# Modify code to export HTML table to Excel

Tags: php, excel, html-table, phpexcel

I'm using `PHPExcel 1.8` in my application. What I want to do is to download my file `generated.html` and this is the content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHPExcel</title>
<style>
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>    
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>Paper</td>    
    <td>123</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>    
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FF0000">John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>    
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

For now, I have `dl.php` to perform the download but `example.xls` doesn't have the styles and colors applied to it.

```
<?php

require_once 'PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML();
$objPHPExcel = @$objReader->load($file_path.'generated.html');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="example.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

What modifications should I do?

Comment: No. Still it is not there in phpEXCEL. You can write own code for it, without using phpexcel. @yowsa

Comment: I see, thanks for the detail.

Comment: Do you need any example for that?? @yowsa

Comment: Sure thing, if you don't mind

Comment: One option is to use jQuery right?

Comment: @yowsa : I tried like generating table and downloading in same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, PHPexcel is not supporting the css and styles. Here is a example code for doing it directly.

This is my `excel.php` file, gives download of table generated inside this file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<title>TESTING</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:12px;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
</style>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $table = '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>';
    $table .= '<tr><td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#000099;color:#FFFFFF;">test</td>';
    $table .= '<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFFF33">TEst</td>';
    $table .= '<td colspan="2" style="background-color:#FFFF33">teST</td>';
    $table .= '<td rowspan="2" style="background-color:#000099;">Test<br>test</td>';
    $table .= '</tr><tr><td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">Test</td>';
    $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">test</td>';
    $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">test</td>';
    $table .= '<td style="background-color:#FFFCCC">test</td>';
    $table .= '</tr><tr></td></tr></table>';

    header("Content-type: application/x-msdownload"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xls"');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    echo $table;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You realise that your code to do those thinsg that PHPExcel can't do, isn't actually generating a real Excel file? Simply an HTML file with a .xls extension. MS Excel is generally forgiving, but recent versions will tell you off severely when you try to open it, telling you that it isn't an Excel file.... no, PHPExcels' HTML Reader doesn't read style information yet.... but at least it's Writers generate __real__ Excel files, and don't simply play "let's pretend"

Comment: @MarkBaker how to remove "The file format and extension of filename.xls don't match" alert box after excel sheet open

Comment: @sunilwananje - this is actually not a excel file, this is html file with excel extension.